# Mongodb get point on LineString $near [lng, lat]

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a document that contains a LineString.  Is it possible to find and return the closest point within the LineString based on a pair of coordinates?

```
db.paths.find( 
  { 
    loc : {
      $near : {
        $geometry : { 
          type : "Point" , 
          coordinates : [-73.965355,40.782865]  
        }, 
        $maxDistance : 20000
      }
  }
);



// My "path" document

loc:{
  "type": "LineString",
  "coordinates": [
    [-2.551082,48.5955632],
    [-2.551229,48.594312],
    [-2.551550,48.593312],
    [-2.552400,48.592312],
    [-2.553677, 48.590898]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As of MongoDB v2.4 (Currently v3.2), `LineString` is one of the supported GeoJSON objects. See [GeoSpatial: GeoJSON Objects](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/applications/geospatial-indexes/#geojson-objects)

Once you create [2dsphere index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/2dsphere/) to the `loc` field, you could query closest points.

Using your example document, a mongo shell query would be :

```js
db.paths.find({
               location:{
                    $nearSphere:{
                          $geometry:{
                               type:"Point", 
                               coordinates:[-2.551010, 48.59123]
                          }, 
                    $maxDistance:2000
                    } 
               }
              });
```

Note that `$maxDistance` is in meters. Your example `find()` coordinates is far beyond the maximum distance you specified.

For v3.2 information please see [$nearSphere](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/nearSphere/#op._S_nearSphere) or [$near](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/query/near/) operators.

Comment: Returns the whole linestring and not a point on the linestring.

Comment: This does not answer the question at all since it does not return the point but the whole line string. This is the default behavior. Useless...